# Automatic line breaks inside \textbf

Tags: macros, pdftex

I'm interested to have an automatic underlining of my definitions, so I've introduced

```
\newcommand\Definition[1]{\underline{\textbf{#1}}}
```

to (the style file, but this is irrelevant)

Now, my problem become noticeable, in case the defined phrase occurs near the end of the line, the text either spills to the margins, or leaves a huge empty space in the end of the line, instead of breaking the line inside the definition.

> How should i redefine the \Definition, so line breaking would be automatic?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Definition[1]{\underline{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Bla bla bla bla lbal bla blablalakasdfdl sdlf sdfl blablalbalasldkfsdflksdf \Definition{here comes the definition}
\end{document}
```

This is the example of page-wide output, the definition spilled to the margins.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `soul` (or `ulem`).  Read the documentation to understand what works and what not inside `\ul`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand\Definition[1]{{\bfseries \ul{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Bla bla bla bla lbal bla blablalakasdfdl sdlf sdfl blablalbalasldkfsdflksdf \Definition{here comes the definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem is with \underline?

Comment: Yes (easy to test, you only need to remove the \textbf to see that the problem doesn't go away).

Comment: On the other hand, underlining boldface text is two mortal typographic sins at once.

Comment: @egreg yes. I would never do it.